# fxml file in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

Good Evening,
I'm taking a course in Java and right now I'm learning JavaFX. I have a  very simple fxml file named sample.fxml. I updated the Main.java file to make the size of the scene a little bigger. When I run the Main.java file, it shows the updated fxml file. However, when I go into scene builder, the fxml file is still the original file. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Joel W

I closed both the scene builder and IntelliJ and re-opened the but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: If you want the FXML to be larger in Scene Builder then change the pref width and pref height of the root element (you can do this in Scene Builder or by manually editing the FXML file). This is separate from the scene you add the loaded FXML to. Scene Builder does not know about that scene (nor should it, unless the `Scene` itself is defined in the FXML, which is not typical). If you want the `Scene` to automatically size itself to the preferred width/height of its root, then don't specify a width and height when instantiating the `Scene`.

Comment: So if I update the fxml file in Intellij such as if I add a button, will the added button show up in scene builder?

Comment: It should, yes. Especially if Scene Builder wasn't open at the time (it should still work with Scene Builder running, but just be careful it doesn't override your changes). "All" Scene Builder does is preview the FXML file and allow you to edit it via a [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor.